# Node JS update global variable using results from Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework

I am using Promise to make a POST request. I am unable to update the global variable `records` using the JSON array returned in the POST request.

```
Export class WalletPage {

  private emailAddress;
  apiUrl = 'someapiurl';
  // records = [
  //   // { fieldA:'1', fieldb:one}, 
  //   // { fieldA:'2', fieldb:two}
  // ];

  records = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.restProvider = new RestProvider(this.httpClient);
  }

  submitEmail() {
    console.log('Trying to submit user email address: ', this.emailAddress);

    var rp = require('request-promise');    

   const payload = {"email_address": this.emailAddress}
   const records = [];
   var options = {
       method: 'POST',
       uri: this.apiUrl + '/order/userRecords',
       body: payload,
       json: true
   };

  rp(options)
  .then(function (parsedBody) {
    // POST succeeded...
     const someResponse = parsedBody.entries
     for (var i = 0, len = someResponse.length; i < len; i++) {
      console.log(someResponse[0]);
      records.push(someResponse[0])
      console.log('someArray is', records)
      this.records = records;
    }

  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    // POST failed
  });  
  }

}
```

It appears `this.records = records;` did not actually update the global variable. I am doing this because the ionic-framework would recognise an array like that and could populate a row in a table for each entry.

ionic-front-end code:

```
  <ion-list-header>
      Your records
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let record of records">
    <ion-label>{{record.fielda}} with value: {{record.fieldb}} </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

this variable is not WalletPage,It is window or something else,you should improve your code like this:

```
rp(options)
  .then((parsedBody) => {
});
```

or:

```
rp(options)
  .then(function (parsedBody) {
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? Does it mean that _this.records_ inside _.then_ is not referring to the class variable records so it was not updated?

Comment: you got it,you may have a try in this method whether if it works